# DSolve to make the path of a ball in a rotating turntable

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have two equations from a analisys of the following situation.
A ball starts to move from the center of a turntable (rotating disk).

[image]

I tried to solve these equations in *Mathematica* but the solution is too long and complex.

I want to make a ball following the solution of these equations.

```
eqx = DSolve[{(x''[t] == w^2 x[t] + 2 w Derivative[1][y][t] + w'[t] (y[t])}, x[t], t]
eqy = DSolve[{(y''[t] ==  w^2 y[t] - 2 w Derivative[1][x][t] - w'[t] (x[t])}, y[t], t]
Equacao = Thread[eqx == eqy]
CondIni = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, C[1] == 1, C[2] == 1, 
  K[1] == 1, K[2] == 0}
Exemplo = Join[Equacao, CondIni]
```

If someone could help with these solutions, or the manipulation of a ball following these equations I'd be grateful..

Answer (score 7):

```
w[t_] := Cos@t
nd = NDSolveValue[{
    x''[t] == w[t]^2 x[t] + 2 w[t] y'[t] + w'[t] y[t],
    y''[t] == w[t]^2 y[t] - 2 w[t] x'[t] - w'[t] x[t],
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1,
    x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];

ParametricPlot[Through[nd[t]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or shorter in vector form:

```
w[t_] := Cos@t
s = RotationMatrix[-Pi/2];

nd = NDSolveValue[{r''[t] == {r[t], s.r'[t], s.r[t]}.{w[t]^2, 2 w[t], w'[t]}, 
                   r[0] == {0, 0}, r'[0] == {0, 1}}, {r}, {t, 0, 10}];

ParametricPlot[Through[nd[t]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: It works... I´ll try to make a manipulate follow this path, theres is a way to make an object, like a ball, follow the path?

Comment: @dcvilela Your previous question was about that!

Comment: Yeah... thats what i´m trying!!